# Xpath help - select a node, then child nodes

Tags: xpath

I'm stumped on why and how to do this query.

My html structure is like this (tables nested inside tables):

```
<root>
<table>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</root>
```

If I start out my xpath like:

```
var tables = blah.SelectNodes("//table");
```

which returns me the 3 parent tables, then I want to select the td's from the 2nd tr like this:

```
var td = tables[2].SelectNodes("//tr[2]/td");
```

But, when I do this, it goes back to the parent/root, the "blah" level. Why is this, and how can I keep filtering my search results down?

Note: The example xml structure may not directly match the queries written, just trying to give a general idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep extending the `XPath`

This one returns the `<tr>` items (four of them) of the second table:

```
/table/tr/td/table/tr
```

This one returns the second `<tr>` item:

```
/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]
```

Your best bet, though, is to give individual `id` attributes to each table, so that you can find it directly using that attribute.

Using something like this:

```
<root>
  <table id="1">
  </table>
  <table id="2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="3">
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</root>
```

You can get the items in the innermost table with:

```
//table[@id="3"]
```

You can get an individual `<td>` item from that innermost table with:

```
//table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[1]
```

Assigning an `id` attribute makes it a little easier (note missing `/tr/td` items after the first `table`):

```
//table[@id="3"]/tr[2]/td[1]
```

Comment: will it still work if I do something like: /table/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tr[2]/td[3] ?

Comment: Thanks Ken, it's not my xml, I'm working on a screen/web scraping project. The html markup is extremely ugly. As soon as I get about 3 layers/elements/nodes deep, I keep getting nulls returned. It's frustrating. I'll try your xpathtester. Thank you.

Comment: @ganders: I just added another sample that should help. I don't know how good xpathtester is; I've got a (now discontinued) tool that I use instead, and just found xpathtester with a quick Google search.